# Can a muslim go to church for christmas event only for the sake of friend's request?

Tags: quran, hadith-interpretation

Some years ago I went to church on the event of christmas only for my friend, I just stayed there for a very small time, later I feel guilty for myself for this act as i think i shouldn't go there. Please clarify me, did I commit sin if yes then what will be my punishment and what will be the kafara or fidyah for this?

What the Quran and hadith says about attending the non-muslims events?

Answer (score 1):

"And never will the Jews or the Christians approve of you until you follow their religion. Say, "Indeed, the guidance of Allah is the [only] guidance." If you were to follow their desires after what has come to you of knowledge, you would have against Allah no protector or helper." Al-Baqarah 120

this ayah is what I can think of.